# Getting days difference between two dates in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with **date picker in react** and have implemented Start and end date which works fine. now I need to get 
the days difference  between the two dates(between Start and End dates).

Here is the problem. Each time I select the two dates to get the difference in days, it only shows the initialize 0 days.
I have resorted to a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844164/react-datepicker)

But still, show **0 days** on date select element. No error message is shown on the console.

**Here is my code**

```
//install the following
//npm i --save react-datepicker
//npm i --save moment

import React from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";


class CheckDate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      days: 0,
    };
    this.handleChangeEnd = this.handleChangeEnd.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeStart = this.handleChangeStart.bind(this);
    this.daysLeft = this.daysLeft.bind(this);

  }

  handleChangeStart(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }


 handleChangeEnd(date) {
    this.setState({
      endDate: date
    });
  }


daysLeft() {
    let {startDate, endDate} = this.state;
    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(endDate);
    let amount = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
    this.setState({
      days: amount
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
     <div>
          <h3>Get Difference between two dates in days</h3>

<b>Start Date</b>:
 <DatePicker
   selected={this.state.startDate}
   onChange={this.handleChangeStart}
 />

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<b>End Date</b>:
 <DatePicker
   selected={this.state.endDate}
   onChange={this.handleChangeEnd}
 />

 <div className="amount">
   {this.state.days}
 </div>

</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You used `daysLeft` method to calculate the days difference but you didn't call it when either of the `startDate` or `endDate` is called so `days` is never updated.

Comment: I realized there was an error in my previous edit, please see the updated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your `daysLeft` method when either of the `startDate` or `endDate` is updated so that it will also update the `days` in the state.

```js
handleChangeStart(date) {
  this.setState({
    startDate: date
  }, () => this.daysLeft());
}


handleChangeEnd(date) {
  this.setState({
    endDate: date
  }, () => this.daysLeft());
}
```

For better code readability, you might want to change the method name from `daysLeft` to something more appropriate of the action like `calculateDaysLeft`, `getDaysLeft` or a better name that you can think of.

### Edit:

This is another implementation based from @Sulthan's comment.

**If the purpose of `days` is for presentation only, then you don't need to store it on the state.** Instead you could get the calculated `days` inside the `render` method itself.

> See working implementation here:
>   https://codesandbox.io/s/4w1496rp4

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import moment from "moment";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

class CheckDate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date()
    };
    this.handleChangeEnd = this.handleChangeEnd.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeStart = this.handleChangeStart.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeStart(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  handleChangeEnd(date) {
    this.setState({
      endDate: date
    });
  }

  calculateDaysLeft(startDate, endDate) {
    if (!moment.isMoment(startDate)) startDate = moment(startDate);
    if (!moment.isMoment(endDate)) endDate = moment(endDate);

    return endDate.diff(startDate, "days");
  }

  render() {
    const { startDate, endDate } = this.state;

    const daysLeft = this.calculateDaysLeft(startDate, endDate);
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Get Difference between two dates in days</h3>
        <b>Start Date</b>:
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChangeStart}
        />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <b>End Date</b>:
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.endDate}
          onChange={this.handleChangeEnd}
        />
        <div className="amount">{daysLeft}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ana Liza, I have implemented your solution but when I select/pick dates. The Date form inputs disappears and this is the error in the console Uncaught TypeError: endDate.diff is not a function
    at CheckDate.daysLeft.

Comment: please can you assist me further. between Thanks for help so far. hoping to hear from you soonest

Comment: @jmarkatti I edited it to include the solution to this error.

Comment: It would be better to call that method only in `render` since it is derived state.

Comment: @Sulthan I agree. Calling it inside will mean, you don't even need to store the `days` in the state anymore.

Comment: @Sulthan I edited the implementation based on your feedback.

Comment: Thanks alot  Liza and Sulthan.